# nc -u 192.168.1.255 9999 fails

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp, broadcast, netcat

I am trying to broadcast to `192.168.1.255` which is my broadcast address. `ifconfig` says

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5:49:51:0b:cb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::52e5:49ff:fe51:bcb/64 Scope:Link
```

but If i do `nc -uv 192.168.1.255 9999` it reports

> nc: connect to 192.168.1.255 port 9999 (udp) failed: Permission denied

**but** `nc -uv 192.168.0.255 9999` works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `socat` instead since some `nc` tools don't support UDP broadcasting.

```
echo "HELLO" | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.255:9999,broadcast
```

Comment: It says `2013/09/03 23:47:25 socat[6518] E unknown device/address "–"`

Comment: @NeelBasu sorry, I fixed the answer. Try again, this time it should work (at least it's working for me with socat 1.7.2.2 on both Archlinux and Mac OS X)

Comment: Confirmed as working on Linux as well, great solution!